# Check if a form is filled or not using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a form with more than 400 hidden fields with values, these values I am getting from a JavaScript file and appending them to a HTML table, then I am getting those values from HTML table cells and appending them to hidden fields and sending them to a PHP file.

Apart from these fields I have some other fields like company name, email etc.. which are not hidden fields, what I need to do here is: I want to check whether even a single hidden field has a value or not, if any hidden field have a value then only email function should work, if all hidden fields are empty then email should not work. Please suggest if there is any simple way to do it. Writing an if condition for 400 fields is not a good idea I think.

For example I am getting those posted values with `$_POST` and assigning them to PHP variables,
I have 400 variables like `$one`, `$two`, `$three`.., `$fourhundred`.

I need to write a condition whether a single variable has a value.

`if(strlen($one) > 0 || strlen($two) > 0 || and so on)`

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the code you have tried? If you read the faqs http://stackoverflow.com/faq you should ask a question which shows you attempted something first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use numeric naming. Instead of one_two_txt, just use 1_2. This way, you can loop through it.

```
$filled = 1;
for($c = 0; $c <= 6; $c++)
{
    if($filled == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    for($r = 0; $r <= 20; $r++)
    {
        if(strlen($_POST["" . $c . "_" . $r . ""]) <= 0)
        {
            $filled = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If $filled is equal to 0, then there is an empty field, so you could post the user back to the form or whatever you want to do.

Comment: @Vamshi Just call your fields like so: column_row (numeric)
So they will go: 1_1, 1_2, 1_3, all the way up to 6_20. It will make it a bit harder to develop the actual functions behind the input fields but you will just have to keep checking for the numeric ID of the field rather than a name.

Answer (score 0):

Are these fields named in any logical way? If so, you can easily achieve this using a loop. If they're named like `email`, `company` etc.. Then it will take some more work.

The way I'd do it is use an array of all of the POST data names you expect.

**Eg:**

```
// Create an array of all of the expected variables
$expectedVars = array("email", "company", "anotherVariable");
$expectedVarNumbers = count($expectedVars);
$varsSoFar = 0;

foreach ($_POST as $key=>$var) {
    if (in_array($key, $expectedVars)) { // If this key is one of the expected vars
        $varsSoFar++;
    }
}

if ($varsSoFar == $expectedVarNumbers) {
    print("All fields have been correctly set!");
} else {
    print("At least one field is missing.");
}
```

Comment: I have 6 columns and 20 rows in my table, each <td> contains a hidden field.. their names are like one_one_txt, one_two_txt etc.. they are named like row_column_txt.. PHP variables also have same names like $one_one_txt and so on..

Comment: @Vamshi Okay, so why don't you try my method above and see if it works for you?